# New record causes to change in a lookup field in different object

Tags: trigger, workflow

We have two custom objects: Obj1 and obj2. Both objects have lookup fields linked to Account. I want "status" field in obj2 to be updated when a new record created for obj1.

Is it possible without a trigger?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @greenstork.

However, if Object 1 is the detail in a Master-Detail relationship with Account you could do something that might get you something that is good enough for whatever it is you are attempting to do.

1. Create a roll-up summary field on Account (e.g., Object 1 Count), that is a COUNT of the related Object 1s (might really only ever be one for your business requirements).
2. Create a formula field on Object 2 to capture that at least one Object 1 exists on the Account.  Here's a very simple implementation: IF( Account__r.Object_1_Count__c > 0, 'Object 1 Created Status', ''). Or, perhaps you might want a checkbox formula.

Comment: If these are both lookups, then a formula field on obj2 is a great idea and completely declarative.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to look down the relationship chain (from parent to child records) to create an automated update without a trigger. There are some declarative tools looking up the chain (from the child to update the parent) but not the other way around.

I guess I would call into question the architecture here a little bit. Obj1 and obj2 clearly have a relationship to each other but are not linked together directly in any way. You may have a good reason for this but it's worth reexamining.